# Automatic categorization or indexing of MediaWiki articles

Tags: mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki instance with thousands of articles in a certain scientific field. They're in a flat space with no categorization. I'd like to organize these automatically using data mining and language-processing techniques. In theory, I think looking for [statistically unlikely phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2aidf) in each document would provide a good starting point.

Right now I can do something like that through the MediaWiki API -- pull down the documents, analyze them, and automatically write back categories or tags.

But is there another way to do this? Looking around the web shows that there's been a huge amount of work on this kind of problem in general -- but nothing that works specifically with MediaWiki in an automated, integrated solution. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial solution, but if you use the [Replace Text](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text) extension you can globally add categories based on specific text. Of course, the categorisation text would then appear wherever the *statistically unlikely phrase* was located:

> you find, "*statistically unlikely phrase*"
>
> you replace it with: "*statistically unlikely phrase + category*"